# MS SQL connection error with PHP on OSX

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2, dbconnection

Connecting to a SQL server which returns the following error: 

`mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: [server ip]`

I'm using the same credentials from SQL client application so I know:
- I can connect to the server from my computer
- the credentials are correct

I'm using PHP on OS X, which I've enabled the `mssql` extension. From what I can there is missing other authentication, which I'm still researching on.

The host contains the server ip and instance name for example [1.1.1.1\InstanceName]

Comment: Does the database allow external connections?

Comment: yes, I can connect to it via `SQLPro for MSSQL` app

Comment: Can you post your config file?

Comment: The host contains the `serverName\instanceName` I think this is the problem